# Angular & Typescript: Controller scope not defined

Tags: angularjs, typescript, partials

I have an angular 1.5 app with Typescript that looks like this:

**mymodule.module.ts:**

```
angular.module('mymodule', []).component('mycomponent', new MyComponent());
```

**mycomponent.component.ts**

```
export class MyController {
    public authorized: boolean;

    constructor() {
        this.authorized = false;
    }

}

export class MyComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    controller = MyController;
    controllerAs = 'vm';
    templateUrl = $partial => $partial.getPath('mytemplate.html');
}
```

**mytemplate.html**

```
...
<div ng-show="vm.authorized">
...
</div>
...
```

The problem is, that vm and vm.authorized is not recognized in mytemplate.html. The div is always shown. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I don't get any error. But vm.authorized seems to not exist. When I check it in the browser's console: angular.element($0).scope().vm, I also get undefined.

Comment: Have you verified that the `templateUrl` function works and returns the proper value?

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML seems incorrectly defined.
Should be `ng-show="vm.authorized"` instead of `ng-show:"vm.authorized"`.

Note the =.

Comment: Oh yes, that was a typo. It is now ng-show="vm.authorized" but the problem exists. It seems that even the vm is not defined.